# How to save string with variables to database?

Tags: php, pdo

I wish to save html email to database.
I've prepared my string witch contains html code and some variables like:

```
$name = "Tom";
$msg = '<p>how are you '.$name.' ?</p>';
$testmsg = htmlentities($msg, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

...than save it with PDO to database.

Problem is that when I'm using htmlentities function `$testmsg` becomes empty...

What should i do to save this string with many variables and call htmlentities?

Comment: Are you sure about this? Empty? Have you tested it? Anyway, with PDO you don't need to use htmlentities().

Comment: i'm shure that in database message field is empty... when i make $msg that contains only html text there is no problem... and its saving properly.

Comment: Ah, the database field. But that's not `$testmsg`. Something between creating `$testmsg`, inserting it in the database, and then reading it, must be wrong. But there's nothing about that in your question.

Comment: it looks like the $testmsg = htmlentities('<p>how are you '.$name.' ?</p>', ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
and i want it to be $testmsg = htmlentities('<p>how are you Tom ?</p>', ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ...

Comment: Sorry I cannot help you, your problem is very simple, but your question is lacking accurate information.

Comment: Please post the whole code. The problem is not in this part of the code.

Comment: ok.. i will update tommorow

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks for the initial troubleshooting, I bet you are right. What does a variable dump (browser-wise i.e. `die($testmsg);` or using logs: `file_put_contents('msg-log.log', $testmsg, FILE_APPEND);`) return?

Comment: Guys i'm verry sory... it seems like ive made mistake in encoding... my text editor is set up to have default ANSI encoding... so when i maked variable where wos some latin characters in UTF8 - saving in ANSI messed up in my functions. Anyway thanks for helping couse youre comments leeded me to this.

Comment: Removed redundant place Fix typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php file that is containing those:

```
$name = "Tom";
$msg = '<p>how are you '.$name.' ?</p>';
$testmsg = htmlentities($msg, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

need to be saved in UTF8.
I've saved it in ANSI by mistake and htmlentities function cleared whole string.